# open window, do some stuff to it as soon as it opens. still is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

Here is what I am ultimately trying to accomplish:

```
Check to see if update is needed
  If update is present - check if window exists
    if exists - add update to window
    If not, open window, setup html and add update
```

Somewhere is the process of the window.open, the windows DOESN'T get created and is causing everything to go NUTS...here is what I am running on

```
var GlobData = [];
GlobData = getMasterData();
var tWin = null;
var timId = 0;
timeId = setInterval(checkCampChange, 1000)
function getMasterData()
{
    var testObj=[];
    $("li.gs-w").each(function(i,j){
        var jj = $(j);
        var PreGroup = jj.children(".widget-container").children(".window-titlebar").children("label").html().split("</i>")[1];
        if (PreGroup.split(" - ").length == 2)
        {
            var GroupId = PreGroup.split(" - ")[0];
            var GroupName = PreGroup.split(" - ")[1];
            var tempObj = {};
            tempObj.GroupId = GroupId;
            tempObj.GroupName = GroupName;

            $("#grid-dashboard .k-grid-content-locked table tr").each(function(i,j)
            {
                var td = $(j).children();
                if ($(td[0]).html() == GroupId)
                {
                    tempObj.List = $(td[1]).html()
                    tempObj.ListName = $(td[2]).html()
                    tempObj.Campaign = $(td[3]).html()
                    tempObj.Status = $(td[4]).html()
                }
            })
            $("#grid-phoneLinesByGroup div.k-grid-content-locked table tr[role='row'] td[role='gridcell']").each(function(i,j)
            {
                var k = $("table[aria-activedescendant='grid-phoneLinesByGroup_active_cell'] tr .duration")[i];
                var GrpId = parseInt($(j).html());
                if(GrpId == GroupId)
                {
                    tempObj.Duration = $(k).html();
                    tempObj.TotalTime = ($(k).html().split(":")[0] * 3600) + ($(k).html().split(":")[1] * 60) + ($(k).html().split(":")[2] * 1)
                }
            });
            testObj.push(tempObj);
        }
    });
    return testObj;
}

function checkCampChange()
{
    var tempGlobData = [];
    tempGlobData = getMasterData();
    $(tempGlobData).each(function(i,tempGlobDataItem){
        $(GlobData).each(function(i,GlobDataItem){
            if (GlobDataItem.GroupId == tempGlobDataItem.GroupId)
            {
                var hasChanged = false
                if (tempGlobDataItem.TotalTime < GlobDataItem.TotalTime)
                {
                    hasChanged = true
                }
                if (tempGlobDataItem.Campaign != GlobDataItem.Campaign)
                {
                    hasChanged = true
                }
                if (hasChanged)
                {
                    tWin = window.open("","campChange","width=300px,height=700");
                    //RIGHT HERE!!!
                    if (!tWin)
                    {
                        setupWindow();
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (!tWin.closed)
                    {
                        setupWindow();
                        return;
                    }
                    $('<div class="msg">' + GlobDataItem.Campaign + " has changed to " + tempGlobDataItem.Campaign + " around " + Date() + '</div>').appendTo(tWin.document.getElementById("holder"));
                    tWin.focus()
                }
            }
        });
    });
    GlobData = tempGlobData.slice(0);
}
function setupWindow()
{
    console.log("SetWindow")
    var jQ = tWin.document.createElement('script');
    jQ.type = 'text/javascript';
    jQ.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';    
    tWin.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jQ);                      
    var script = tWin.document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.innerHTML = 'var isLoaded = true;';    
    tWin.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);  
    var ssty = tWin.document.createElement('style');
    ssty.innerHTML = 'body{background:gray;}.msg{padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;border-bottom:1px solid black}';    
    tWin.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(ssty);
    tWin.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = "<div style='margin: 5px;background: white;width: auto;padding: 4px;height: 35px;border-radius: 5px;font-size: 32px;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;'>Camp Tracker</div>" + "<div id='holder' style='margin: 5px;background: white;width: auto;padding: 4px;height: 628px;border-radius: 5px;overflow-y: auto;'></div>";
}
```

Here is what is in GlobData:

```
"[
  {
    "GroupId": "1",
    "GroupName": "Merp",
    "List": "10104",
    "ListName": "MERP",
    "Campaign": "MERP",
    "Status": "<span class=\"group-background-color dialing\">Dialing</span>",
    "Duration": "00:16:44",
    "TotalTime": 1004
  },
  {
    "GroupId": "4",
    "GroupName": "Client",
    "List": "20002",
    "ListName": "CLIENT",
    "Campaign": "CLNT",
    "Status": "<span class=\"group-background-color dialing\">Dialing</span>",
    "Duration": "00:23:19",
    "TotalTime": 1399
  }
]"
```

In checkCampChange, i do the window.open to get a completely blank window of a particular size. Once open, it is supposed to runs setupWindow. this will setup all html, styles and other JS stuff. BUT it errors out in the checkCampChange where I have marked. when I step thru the code, it runs fine. it just doens't seem to be creating the windows quick enough and erroring on the next if statement.

Let me know what yinz think

Comment: *"If update is present - check if window exists"* If `window` didn't exist, you couldn't be running your code. `window` always exists from the code's perspective.

Comment: that is why i do the tWin = window.open...it just doesn't create the window

Answer (score 0):

I decided that instead of opening a new window and having to used minified strings of html, javascript and CSS injected into a blank window, I just made a div that slides out and can be hidden down to 20 px

CSS:

```
.blink_me 
{
    animation: blinker 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes blinker 
{
    50% { opacity: 0; }
}
.sidenav 
{
    left:-230px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 32px;
}


.navWrap 
{
    float: left;
    height: 700px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.sidenav a 
{
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidenav .closebtn 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: 15px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.sidenav h1
{
    padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#holder
{
    color: white;
    border: 1px white solid;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    width: 185px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.sidenav .msg 
{
    padding: 8px 19px 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidenav a:hover 
{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav a:hover 
{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
.remCamp 
{
    cursor:pointer;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 22px;
}

#opener 
{
    cursor:pointer;
    float: right;
    color: white;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) 
{
    .sidenav 
    {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a 
    {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
var GlobData = [];
var timeId;
doStartUp();

function doStartUp()
{
    //alert("Loaded");
    if (timeId > 0)
    {
        clearInterval(timeId);
    }
    if($("#wallboardCSS").length != 0)
    {
        $("#wallboardCSS").remove();
    }
    if($("#wallboardauxJS").length != 0)
    {
        $("#wallboardauxJS").remove();
    }
    if($("#mySidenav").length != 0)
    {
        $("#mySidenav").remove();
    }

    $('<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav"><div class="navWrap"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a><h1>Camp Track</h1><div id="holder"></div></div><div id="opener">>></div></div>').appendTo("body");
    //<link href="http://localhost:8080/css/wallboard.css" rel="stylesheet" id="wallboardCSS">
    $('<link href="http://localhost:8080/css/wallboard.css" rel="stylesheet" id="wallboardCSS">').appendTo("head");
    //<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/js/wallboard-aux.js" id="wallboardauxJS"></script>
    $('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/js/wallboard-aux.js" id="wallboardauxJS"></script>').appendTo("head");
    GlobData = getMasterData();
    timeId = setInterval(checkCampChange, 1000);
}
function getMasterData()
{
    var testObj=[];
    $("li.gs-w").each(function(i,j){
        var jj = $(j);
        var PreGroup = jj.children(".widget-container").children(".window-titlebar").children("label").html().split("</i>")[1];
        if (PreGroup.split(" - ").length == 2)
        {
            var GroupId = PreGroup.split(" - ")[0];
            var GroupName = PreGroup.split(" - ")[1];
            var tempObj = {};
            tempObj.GroupId = GroupId;
            tempObj.GroupName = GroupName;

            $("#grid-dashboard .k-grid-content-locked table tr").each(function(i,j)
            {
                var td = $(j).children();
                if ($(td[0]).html() == GroupId)
                {
                    tempObj.List = $(td[1]).html()
                    tempObj.ListName = $(td[2]).html()
                    tempObj.Campaign = $(td[3]).html()
                    tempObj.Status = $(td[4]).html()
                }
            })
            $("#grid-phoneLinesByGroup div.k-grid-content-locked table tr[role='row'] td[role='gridcell']").each(function(i,j)
            {
                var k = $("#grid-phoneLinesByGroup .duration.column-timer")[i];//$("table[aria-activedescendant='grid-phoneLinesByGroup_active_cell'] tr .duration")[i];
                var GrpId = parseInt($(j).html());
                if(GrpId == GroupId)
                {
                    tempObj.Duration = $(k).html();
                    tempObj.TotalTime = ($(k).html().split(":")[0] * 3600) + ($(k).html().split(":")[1] * 60) + ($(k).html().split(":")[2] * 1)
                }
            });
            testObj.push(tempObj);
        }
    });
    return testObj;
}

function checkCampChange()
{
    var tempGlobData = [];
    tempGlobData = getMasterData();
    var hasChanged = false
    $(tempGlobData).each(function(i,tempGlobDataItem){
        $(GlobData).each(function(i,GlobDataItem){
            if (GlobDataItem.GroupId == tempGlobDataItem.GroupId)
            {
                if (tempGlobDataItem.TotalTime < GlobDataItem.TotalTime)
                {
                    hasChanged = true
                }
                if (tempGlobDataItem.Campaign != GlobDataItem.Campaign)
                {
                    hasChanged = true
                }
                if (hasChanged)
                {
                    var tdate = new Date;
                    var dd = getTime(tdate);
                    var tName = "msg" + tdate.getTime();
                    $('<div class="msg blink_me" id="' + tName + '">Group ' + GlobDataItem.GroupId + ': ' + GlobDataItem.Campaign + " has changed to " + tempGlobDataItem.Campaign + " around " + dd + '<div class="remCamp">&times;</div></div>').appendTo("#holder");
                    $("#" + tName).click(unBlink);
                    $("#" + tName + " .remCamp").click(remCamp);

                    hasChanged = false;
                    if($("#opener").css("display") == "block")
                    {
                        $("#opener").addClass("blink_me");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
    GlobData = tempGlobData.slice(0);
    console.log("window check")

}

function getTime(td)
{
    var dd = "";
    if (td.getHours()==0)
    {
        dd = "12";
    }
    else if (td.getHours() > 12)
    {
        dd = (td.getHours() - 12).toString();
    }
    else
    {
        dd = td.getHours().toString();
    }
    console.log(dd.length);
    if (dd.length == 1)
    {
        dd = "0" + dd;
    }
    dd += ":";
    if (td.getMinutes() < 10)
    {
        dd += "0" + td.getMinutes();
    }
    else if (td.getHours() > 12)
    {
        dd += td.getMinutes();
    }

    if (td.getHours() > 12)
    {
        dd += " PM";
    }
    else
    {
        dd += " AM";
    }


    return dd;
}
```

JS Aux:

```
function openNav() 
{
    $("#mySidenav").css("left","0px");
    $("#opener").hide();
}
function closeNav() 
{
    $("#mySidenav").css("left","-230px");
    $("#opener").show();
    if($("#opener").hasClass("blink_me"))
    {
        $("#opener").removeClass("blink_me");
    }
    $(".msg").each(function (i,j){
        $(j).removeClass("blink_me");
    })
}
function remCamp()
{
    $(this).parent().remove();
}
function unBlink()
{
    $(this).removeClass("blink_me");
}


$("#opener").click(openNav);
$(".closebtn").click(closeNav);
```

I load it from our web server using a bookmark with the following:

```
javascript:if($("#wallboardJS").length != 0){$("#wallboardJS").remove();}$('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/js/wallboard.js" id="wallboardJS"></script>').appendTo("head");
```